# ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/stylesheets/bootstrap-theme.css.map.css"):

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

- rails 4.1.7
- ruby-2.1.4
- gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
- gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.1'
- gem
  'autoprefixer-rails'

I installed bootstrap following these instructions https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass

I have an app/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap-theme.css.map but no an app/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap-theme.css.map.css

This is my /app/assets/stylesheets/application.css

```
body { padding-top: 60px;
    padding-left: 50px;
     }

@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed the file extension from bootstrap-theme.css.map.css to bootstrap-theme.css.map

Answer (score 2):

There's a line at the bottom of bootstrap.css that you can uncomment to fix this:

```
sourceMappingURL=bootstrap.css.map
```

Comment: Life saver. Thank you @TenJack